# Number of Subsets of power set of null set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \varnothing$.

Now $\wp(A) = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$

$\wp(\wp(A))= \{\varnothing, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}$

So I am getting 4 elements but answer is 2. Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: $P(A)=\{\emptyset \}$ and $P(P(A))=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset \} \}$

Comment: So if A would have been {$\emptyset$}, my answer is correct?

Comment: Yes (right now your $P(P(A))$ is $P(P(P(A)))$, and your $P(A)$ is actually $P(P(A))$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for every set A $\rightarrow |P(A)|=2^{|A|}$.

$A=\emptyset\rightarrow |A|=0 \rightarrow |P(A)|=2^{|\emptyset|}=2^0=1$

If your remember this fact, it might be easier for you to recall that $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$

Then, $P(P(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\Rightarrow |P(P(\emptyset))|=2$